# python 2.7 cPickle append List

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I am trying to write to append to a list using cPickle in **python 2.7** but it does not append.

**Code:**

```
import cPickle
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]]);
output = open("1.pkl",'wb');
cPickle.dump(a,output);
a = numpy.array([[4, 5],[6, 7]]);
output = open("1.pkl",'ab');
cPickle.dump(a,output);
print(cPickle.load(open("1.pkl",'rb')));
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 2]
[3 4]]
```

I was using this method to append the arrays in text files before

**Code:**

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]]);
text_file = open("1.txt", "w");
numpy.savetxt(text_file, a);
text_file.close();
a = numpy.array([[4, 5],[6, 7]]);
text_file = open("1.txt", "a");
numpy.savetxt(text_file, a);
text_file.close();

text_file = open("1.txt", "r");
print(text_file.read());
```

**Output:**

```
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00
```

I Was using this to write the data of a python simulation I setup for Power Systems. The output data is huge around 7GB. And the writing process was slowing down the simulation a lot. I read that cPickle can make writing process faster.

**How do I append to the cPickle output file without having to read the whole data?**

**Or is there a better alternative to cPickle to make writing faster?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can just append to a pickle, or in a way that makes sense anyway.

If you just get the current serialized version of an object and add another serialized object at the end of the file, it wouldn't just magically append the second object to the original list.

You would need to read in the original object, append to it in Python, and then dump it back.

```
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np

filename = '1.pkl'

a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
b = np.array([[4, 5],[6, 7]])

# dump `a`
with open(filename,'wb') as output_file:
    pickle.dump(a, output, -1)

# load `a` and append `b` to it
with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
    old_data = pickle.load(output_file)
    new_data = np.vstack([old_data,a])

# dump `new_data`
with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    pickle.dump(new_data, output_file, -1)

# test
with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
    print(pickle.load(output_file))
```

After reading your question a second time, you state that you don't want to read in the whole data again. I suppose this doesn't answer your question then, does it?